# Accessing the value of a variable by its name as string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string containing the variable name. I want to get the value of that variable.

```
int temp = 10;
String temp_name = "temp";
```

Is it possible to access the value `10` by using `temp_name`?

Comment: Why? For what reason? What purpose are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest that you use a `Map<String, Integer>` instead:

Create the map by doing

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then change

```
int temp = 10;
```

to

```
values.put("temp", 10);
```

and access the value using

```
int tempVal = values.get(temp_name);
```

Comment: +1 This is a better solution to the problem, and there should be no reason why you cannot take this approach.

Comment: @ErickRobertson  I agree.  Reflection is a solution to a 'not ordinary' need, whereas a newbie is typically needing a map or associative array.

Answer (score 10):

**Make the variable a member variable and use reflection.**

You cannot get the value by name of a variable unless it's a member variable of a class.  Then you can use the `java.lang.reflect` package to retrieve the value.