# Getting a variable's value when you only have the variable name as a String

Tags: java

```
int text01=2012；
String entrance= "text01";
```

How could I get the `int value(2012)` of 'text01' through String 'entrance'?

Comment: I'm sure the answer to your question is very simple. I just can't understand your question... Please rephrase it.

Comment: I think he's meaning an eval()-like expression...

Comment: You can attempt to use reflection if it's a field.

Comment: @TehHippo But there is no eval() in Java, reflection may be a good way.

Comment: @user158626 -> Aware of that, hence the -like ;)  eval()-like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the value of a variable by its name as string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141542/accessing-the-value-of-a-variable-by-its-name-as-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what the class is, you can use reflection:

```
public class Test
{
    int text01 = 2012;
}
```

And somewhere else, you can get that field's value by:

```
String entrance = "text01";
Test t = new Test();

Field f = t.getClass().getDeclaredField(entrance);
System.out.println("value = "+f.getInt(t));

// you can even change the value:
t.text01 = 2013;
System.out.println("value = "+f.getInt(t));
```

This will print out `2012`, then `2013`.

Comment: I'm hoping it'll be a lot simpler than that :)

Answer (score 2):

The integer variable `text01` and the value `text01` stored in a string variable are two different things.

It is not possible to get the value of a variable like this because both the **int** variable `text01` and the value stored in the **string** variable `text01` have nothing to do with each other.

**Update:**

In case someone is looking for a simple approach to this using map is a good option. Just store variable names as keys and their values as key values

```
    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    int text01=2012;
    String entrance= "text01";

    m.put(entrance, text01);
```

to get the value

```
m.get(entrance);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want is something like this:
`public Map values = new HashMap();
values.add("text01", 2012);`

System.out.println(values.get("text01"));

Comment: Yes, Map is a good way, but I want to find a smarter way to get the value, not always putting the value into a Map before getting this value. @TehHippo

Comment: I would question why you want to access it in this way.  It's not really how Java was designed.  Reflections can do what you need, see the post above, but I'd be thinking about approaching the problem differently.  Using a map is a smart way of doing it and ultimately would result in the same outcome.

The reason is because the variable text01 has a value of 2012, but the variable name (text01), is being used like a variable.  Two variables, Map<var, var> is the most logical.  Reflections might be what you want, but it could easily be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> int text01=2012；
>
> String entrance= "text01";

2012 and test01 are two different values that having different references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils class for this.

```
int text01 = 2012;
String entrance = "text01";
```

Just use : 
if your class object is Test test = new Test();

```
Object value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(test, entrance);
```