# How to name a variable as value of another variable in java?

Tags: java

I want to give name to a variable same as value of some other variable. I am new to java and have no idea how to do it .
Suppose `String s="stack";` now suppose I want to **name integer variable as stack using s **.How can I do it?my variable name should be stack.

Comment: so what you want to do is:
Integer stack = new Integer(5); // stack, because that's the value of your String?
you can't.

Comment: For an alternative solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11141579/733368

Comment: This is a common newbie question, and the answer is that it's not possible, in Java or in most other languages (a few can do it).  But what you want to do almost certainly can be done using arrays or Maps, so study up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two words: **You can't**. (In Java)

**EDIT**

No alternative which does the same but [here is something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141542/accessing-the-value-of-a-variable-by-its-name-as-string-in-java/) which does similar.

Comment: Thanks!!any alternative of what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as described it is impossible. The closest things coming to my mind is `Map`:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//some code to fill it
String s = "stack";

Object value = map.get(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you said is possible in language like PHP as

```
$s = 'stack';
${$s} = 'hello there';
echo $stack; // hello there
```

But it is not possible in strongly typed langauge like Java, C# etc.